# Ansible script is executing but loop is failing

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a script (`adduser.yml`) to create users in a linux machine which imports users list from `userlist.csv` file. When I executed adduser.yml, the loop failed creating only 1st user. Can someone help me understand what mistake I am doing and how to correct it?

userlist.csv:

```
id,username,password,sudo
1,ansible1,ansible@123,yes
2,ansible2,ansible@123,no
3,ansible3,ansible@123,yes
4,ansible4,ansible@123,yes
```

adduser.yml:

```
---
## executed but until loop failed; check 
- hosts: 192.168.0.3
  vars:
    count: "{{COUNT}}"
    x: "1"
    uname: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{x}} file=userlist.csv delimiter=, col=1') }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{x}} file=userlist.csv delimiter=, col=2') }}"
    sudo: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{x}} file=userlist.csv delimiter=, col=3') }}"

  tasks:
    name: "user add"
    action:
     - user:
         x: "x+=1"
         name: "{{ uname }}"
         password: "{{ password }}"
         state: present
    register: x
    until: "{{x > count}}"

    name: "add to sudoers"
    when: sudo == "yes"
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite some things that will not work as you expected them. First thing, your loop is defined for your first task. That means only the `user` task will be repeated. Neither the sudo task nor the vars definition at the top will be looped. But don't try to re-define your loop, this is not going to work with vars.

Ansible has no build-in way to read vars from a csv file other than the csv lookup which will read exactly one line. But as said, you can not combine that with a loop.

I see two options you have:

1. Do not use csv. Ansible is mostly bound to yaml. If you'd had a yaml definition of your users, you simply could use the `include_vars` module to load these vars.
2. If you are bound to csv, you could try to use this [includecsv module](https://galaxy.ansible.com/detail#/role/6589). (I have no experience with it and can not tell if it actually works)

Now, let's assume you have loaded your users into a list either from yaml or from csv with mentioned module. Then you'd simply loop with `with_items`:

```
tasks:
  - name: "user add"
    user:
       name: "{{ item['uname'] }}"
       password: "{{ item['password'] }}"
       state: present
    with_items: users_you_loaded

  - name: "add to sudoers"
    when: "{{ item['sudo'] }} == 'yes'"
    ... 
    with_items: users_you_loaded
```